# But seem like he didn't study much but still can do well in the exam

Tags: grammaticality

Why cannot write "studies" instead of "study"?

Comment: Because the sentence is in the past tense. So it can't be "studies", it can only be "studied". "He studied much." But there is also a negation, so the past tense is taken by the helper verb "did". And so the main verb does not have to indicate anything at all, and stays in the infinitive. "He *studied* much, he *did* not *study* much". "He *studies* much, he *does* not *study* much".

Comment: Auxiliary _do_ (including _does_, _don't_, _doesn't_, _did_, and _didn't_) is **always** followed by the base form of the main verb, irrespective of tense.

Answer (score 1):

OP's text consists of 2 superficially contradictory assertions...

> 1: *[seem like] **he didn't study much***
>    2: ***he still can do well in the exam***

...where it should be noted that ***seem like*** is syntactically invalid (acceptable alternatives include ***It seems like..., It appears [that]..., Apparently...***). Also note that *idiomatically*, native speakers normally put adverbial ***still*** between the auxiliary ("helper") verb ***can*** and the main ("infinitive") verb ***do***, as ***he can still do well***.

It should also be noted that there should only be ***one*** "contrastive" conjunction in a sentence juxtaposing two contradictory assertions. Acceptable constructions here include...

> 3: ***Although*** he didn't study much, he still can do well in the exam
>    4: *He didn't study much, **but** he still can do well in the exam*
>    5: *He didn't study much, **although** he still can do well in the exam*

(Where #5 is idiomatically unlikely in most contexts, so it's probably best to assume you should always choose between using ***although*** before the first assertion, OR ***but*** before the second.)

---

Turning to the *specific* point being asked about (why is it ***study***, not ***studies***?), this is addressed by [@ЯegDwight's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/238548/but-seem-like-he-didnt-study-much-but-still-can-do-well-in-the-exam#comment452065_238548):

> *the past tense is taken by the helper verb "**did**". And so the main verb [**study**] does not have to indicate anything at all, and **stays in the infinitive***

That's to say, if a multi-word verb form includes an [*auxiliary verb*](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/auxiliary-or-helping-verbs/) (such as ***can*** and ***didn't*** here), we only inflect the auxiliary verb for tense, not the "main" verb (***study*** and ***do*** here). This rule is unaffected by whether negating ***not / n't*** is present.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it